# Disable csrf toke for some routes in laravel 5.4? Not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am making an API for my website, API will be used to get, post, delete some data, but to post, csrf token is needed which cannot be generated from third party websites, so I have to disable csrf token for some routes. In documentation it says to add following in verifycsrftoken.php:

```
protected $except = [
    'leads',
    'leads/*'
];
```

But this is not working in laravel 5.4. 
Here is my sample route:

```
Route::post('leads/{id}', ['as'=>'leads']);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That should work fine. You're still getting a CSRF exception?

Comment: It says 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException'

Comment: That's probably a POST/GET mismatch. What does your form tag look like?

Comment: @AhmadRza That is **not a CSRF issue.** It's a separate problem.

Comment: @ceejayoz this is not a duplicate of that question, their context and mine is totally different...

Comment: @AhmadRza It is the same issue. You are either POSTing to a GET route or GETting to a POST route. Check `php artisan route:list`. If you disagree, edit your question to add the `<form>` tag or code you're using to call the API and your `Route::get/post` definitions and I'll consider re-opening.

Comment: I have resolved the issue, thanks everybody..

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted should work.

As you said in your comment, the error is `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. That error in thrown when you try to visit a url with the wrong type. In order to send the form via POST, you will need to indicate in the form tag

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('leads/'.$lead->id) }}>
```

and also add the csrfToken inside the form

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Comment: command app/Http/kernal.php in  \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class no need to use csrf token

Comment: Sorry but I said im calling api from third party website, third party website cannot generate csrf tokens for my main website, and Im calling api via ajax..

Comment: Make sure you're calling the API from POST instead of GET then.

Comment: resolved, i was just checking whether its working or not just by typing in the url, it was not, but using ajax, it worked...

Comment: Typing on the URL of your browser will do the request via GET. You can check POST routes using Postman.